# Выдает ошибку при считывании файла в Си

Tags: c, файлы

Не могу разобраться, где ошибка в **while (!feof(f)) {**. В данной функции производится считывание данных в список из файла.
P.S (Функция **GetLine()** возвращает указатель на строку, которую ввел пользователь)

```
list* InputFile(void) {
    list* head = NULL;
    list* tmp;
    FILE* f;
    char* filename;
    puts("Введите имя файла:");
    while (!(fopen_s(&f,(filename = GetLine()), "r"))) {
        system("cls");
        puts("Файла с таким именем нет, повторите ввод: ");
        free(filename);
    }
    while (!feof(f)) {
        tmp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list)), CheckMem(tmp);
        fscanf_s(f, "%d", &(tmp->value));
        head = PushEnd(head, tmp);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка выдается?

Comment: Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Laba 3\Debug\Laba 3.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\feoferr.cpp
Line: 17

Expression: public_stream != nullptr

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас задано неправильно условие в этом `while` предложении

```
while (!(fopen_s(&f,(filename = GetLine()), "r"))) {
       ^^
```

Согласно описанию функции `fopen_s` она

> **Возвращает нуль в случае успеха** или код ошибки в случае неудачи

Поэтому условие должно выглядеть так

```
while ( fopen_s(&f,(filename = GetLine()), "r") ) {
```

То есть пока возникает ошибка (то есть функция возвращает не 0), продолжать цикл.

Еще более ясным выглядело бы условие цикла, если его задать в виде

```
while ( fopen_s(&f,(filename = GetLine()), "r") != 0 ) {
```

Кроме того, данное условие второго цикла

```
while (!feof(f)) {
```

также не совсем корректное, которое может привести к дублированию последнего прочитанного значения. Вам надо делать условие цикла в зависимости от успешности или неуспешности вызова `fscanf_s`.

И в конце функции вам следует освободить память, указываемую указателем `filename`.

Answer (score 2):

У @VladfromMoscow все верно об `feof`, но очень кратко. Поясню подробнее - о том, что достигнут конец файла, программа узнает, **только попытавшись прочесть что-то за его концом**.

Так что цикл

```
while (!feof(f)) {
    // Чтение файла
}
```

приводит к тому, что последнее чтение файла, после которого `feof(f)` ответит `true`, должно быть неуспешным. Поэтому проверять нужно успешность результата чтения, а не флаг конца файла. Так что я бы действовал примерно так -

```
int v;
while (fscanf_s(f, "%d", &v) == 1) {
    tmp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list)), CheckMem(tmp);
    tmp->value = v;
    head = PushEnd(head, tmp);
}
```